# Xamarin Forms, MS Azure Crashes not working on iOS

Tags: ios, azure, xamarin

I followed [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/sdk/getting-started/Xamarin) and added `Analytics` and `Crashes` **correctly** to **`Android`** but in `iOS` only `Analytics` added correctly. for checking if `Crashes` is working on iOS, I created some crashes like so:

1.

```
int a = 0;
int b = 2 / a;
```

2.

```
throw new Exception("jiiiiz");
```

3.

```
Crashes.GenerateTestCrash();
```

but non of them are reported to azure crashes panel, I also check if an error happen in next session app is opened but it's always `false`:

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        var a = Crashes.HasCrashedInLastSession;
        Debug.WriteLine($"Crashed?? {a}"); // is always false
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the link you followed for us to check this issue?

Comment: @Bruce-MSFT, Oh sorry and thanks for reminding, I've added the link

Answer (score 0):

As  Mobile Center Crashes documentation mentioned about **Troubleshooting**:

> Right now crash reports are only visible if they can be **symbolicated**. **For that to happen the proper symbols (dSYM) need to be uploaded**. There will be a UI available later that shows which symbols are missing and how to find them.
>
> **Make sure the app doesn't crash on startup**, as the SDK wouldn't have time to send the crash report. This is a limitation for any 3rd party crash reporting service.

For how to provide symbols for your app, you could refer to [Uploading symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/crashes/ios#uploading-symbols).